# How to read and store minimum value displayed on the frequency sink in GNU Radio - Python code

Tags: python, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, software-defined-radio

I am trying to read and store the gain value of the received signal using the QT GUI Frequency Sink block in GNU Radio.
Is there any block that I can use to store this value?

Here is the graph that shows the gain of the signal:
[image: Frequency SInk]

The stored value in this case should be around -19.8 dB:
[image: Value to store]

Comment: what is the problem? Where is your code? Do you get error message or wrong results? We can't see your code and we can't read in your mind - so we have no idea what is your problem. And don't expect that we will write all code to resolve this problem. You should show some code which we could modify.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. A visualization is a visualization!

You want to programmatically calculate a spectrum estimate, find the maximum value, and safe that to a "File Sink" directly. That's easy:

- source
- -> stream to vector (vector length: desired FFT length)
- -> FFT (length: desired fft length)
- -> complex to mag² (vector length: fft length)
- -> Max (vector length: fft length)
- -> log10 (n=10)
- -> File sink

In case this seems like a challenge, you'll want to read the official tutorials on https://tutorials.gnuradio.org; and, I generally recommend reading the block documentation (linked from the "Documentation" tab in the block properties dialog), *especially* on the [File Sink](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=File_Sink).